# FastAPI Authentication fail when using github actions for automated testing

Tags: python, authentication, github-actions, fastapi

I'm trying to get my Github Action tests to pass but 6/8 of them fail due to 401 (Unauthorised). The only ones that pass are my 'sign in' endpoint (`@router.post("/token")`) and my validation test that makes sure the `JWT_SECRET_KEY` is being read in. Interestingly all my tests pass locally. The secret key is used to sign the JWT tokens.

Below is my Github Action which is used to automate the API tests on commits to main or dev as well as pulls to main.

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev", "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.11
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.11"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        pip install -r backend/requirements.txt
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test backend tests
      env:
        JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET_KEY }}
      run: |
        # run backend tests
        pytest backend/tests/tests.py
    - name: Check test status
      if: ${{ failure() }}
      run: exit 1
```

My authentication process works pretty much the exact same way as on the FastAPIs website ([oauth2-jwt](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/))

My test code is as follows, I've only included 3 of test. The first test `test_secret_keys` tests that the `JWT_SECRET_KEY` is not None, this passes. The second `test_authentication` passes but `test_authenticated_user_access` fails:

```
import pytest
import os

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from .test_utils import FakeUser
from settings import ROOT, PROJECT_DIR
from api import app
from db.database import SessionLocal
from db.models import DbBlog

automatic_fields = ['timestamp', 'id', 'image_url']
files_dir = os.path.join(ROOT, 'files')
client = TestClient(app)
user = FakeUser("a", "a")


def get_header():
    response = client.post("http://localhost:8000/token",
                           data={"grant_type": "password",
                                 "username": user.username,
                                 "password": user.password})

    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
        return {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}


@pytest.fixture
def delete_all_data():
    """
    This fixture runs on all tests apart from delete. This allows delete to be run on its own as well as with all tests.
    """

    # clean db
    session = SessionLocal()
    session.query(DbBlog).delete()
    session.commit()
    session.close()

    # clean dir with images
    if os.path.exists(files_dir):
        all_image_files = os.listdir(files_dir)
        for file in all_image_files:
            if file != '.gitkeep':
                os.remove(os.path.join(files_dir, file))


@pytest.fixture
def fake_data():
    response = client.post('/post', json={"user_name": "test name",
                                          "title": "test title",
                                          "content": "test content"},
                           headers=get_header())


def test_secret_keys():
    assert os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET_KEY") is not None


def test_authentication(delete_all_data):
    """
    Authenticate fake user and check they can access a restricted endpoint
    """

    response = client.post("http://localhost:8000/token",
                             data={"grant_type": "password",
                                   "username": user.username,
                                   "password": user.password})

    assert response.status_code == 200


def test_authenticated_user_access(delete_all_data):
    response = client.get("http://localhost:8000/users/me", headers=get_header())
    assert response.status_code == 200

...
```

Token endpoint and test authenticated user access endpoint:

```
@router.post("/token")
async def login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires)
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

@router.get("/users/me")
async def read_users_me(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return current_user
```

Its worth noting that the tests passed both locally and during push before I added in authentication.

For for information / code please visit my [repo](https://github.com/RamonJWS/fast-api-blog/tree/dev/backend)

Would really appreciate a solution to this, i'm close to removing the test automation entirely... Thanks!

Comment: Start by verifying whether you actually get a token back - if you don't get a token, it doesn't matter what the secret key used for signing is - it was never used. Are you sure you have a `username` / `password` combination set up? You're not running alembic or anything similar in your GA, so I'm not sure where you'd populate the database. Since you haven't included the `/token` endpoint, is hard for someone else to say whether `200` actually means that the user was authenticated successfully.

Comment: I can confirm that i get a token back when hitting the `/token` endpoint while working locally. My user information is in a json file, once things are working I plan to move the into their own table in my db. I'll include the `/token' endpoint in the description. Thanks @MatsLindh

Comment: How is `SECRET_KEY` being used in your code? In https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/, `SECRET_KEY` is being used with encoding and decoding API calls. Please add the relevant parts of how it is being accessed and used in your code. Thanks!

Comment: Before I get into this, I can confirm that my github actions secret key is set up correctly, and that the key is read inside the script. I confirmed this by adding in a new test that checks that the SECRET_KEY being loaded from `os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")` in not None. This isn't a super rigours test, but as I'm using only one environment variable its unlikely this value is the wrong one.

My `SECRET_KEY` is being used to create and access token, this token is created from the username and a token expiry time (1hour added to UTC). @Azeem

Comment: My `SECRET_KEY` is also being used to decode any endpoint requests that require authentication, this is done by using the JWT token in the authentication bearer header request and decoding it using `jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM]`, I then ensure that the decoded JWT has the username that matches the authenticated user. I'll include the code snippets in the above question but It might just be easier to view the code on my [github](https://github.com/RamonJWS/fast-api-blog/tree/dev/backend). Thanks for your interest in this issue! @Azeem

Comment: In your workflow, it is `env: SECRET_KEY` but in your code you're fetching `JWT_SECRET_KEY` env var.

Comment: My apologies, this was a typo in my question (corrected above). My source code has the correct mapping. @Azeem

Comment: Can you please reverify `JWT_SECRET_KEY` by printing it in square brackets `[...]`? It's a secret so it will be redacted and there'll be asterisks only. But, it'll make sure that there's no newline at the end or some other preceding or trailing white space causing this. You can do that by adding `echo "JWT_SECRET_KEY: [$JWT_SECRET_KEY]"` [here before running tests](https://github.com/RamonJWS/fast-api-blog/actions/runs/4778155963/workflow#L39).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, of course I will change the key now that it can be viewed in the logs. FYI `echo "JWT_SECRET_KEY: [$JWT_SECRET_KEY]"` didn't work as expect, it returned `[***]`, however, using `echo ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET_KEY }} | sed 's/./& /g'` returned the key with space between characters. E.g. `c a a 9 7 5 9 a 4 4` which is indeed the start of my secret key minus the spaces. @Azeem

Comment: `[***]` was expected. Secrets are redacted in the logs automatically. The same key works fine locally?

Comment: Yes, the key works fine locally. All my tests pass locally without issue, i've also manually tested the authentication process through FastAPIs auto documentation with no issues. I have also tried changing the Github Actions OS to match my local OS (MacOS) but GH action tests still fail :/ @Azeem

Comment: I got it to work! I think there must have been an error in the string I submitted as my secret key in github, when i updated the key it passed. Thanks a tone for your suggestions @Azeem

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear that. Glad you figured it out. All the best! :)